# i am getting Traceback Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, json

Hi all I have almost finished my app and the moment I thought I had it working like I wanted I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "Sydneyimport.py", line 10, in  for element in response_data['response_data']: KeyError: 'response_data' –
>    error Traceback

I have done some research and can't find the problem with my code.  I am new to doing this so it might be something small.

```
import urllib.parse
import requests

main_api = 'https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/_a/flights/?query=&flightType=departure&terminalType=domestic&date=2019-11-10&sortColumn=scheduled_time&ascending=true&showAll=true'

address = 'lhr'
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({address: address})

response_data = requests.get(url).json()
for element in response_data['response_data']:
    id = element['id']
    airline = element['airline']
    destination = element['destinations']
    flightNumbers = element['flightNumbers']
    scheduledTime = element['scheduledTime']
    estimatedTime = element['estimatedTime']
    scheduledDate = element['scheduledDate']
    latestTime = element['latestTime']
    status = element['status']
    statusColor = element['statusColor']

print (airline, destinations, flightNumbers)
```

Comment: Whats the full error?

Comment: here it is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Sydneyimport.py", line 10, in <module>
    for element in response_data['response_data']:
KeyError: 'response_data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will check the response, you are looking at the wrong place. The data your are looking for is coming inside flightData. I have updated the code to check inside flightData and print. Hope this helps.

```py
import urllib.parse
import requests

main_api = 'https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/_a/flights/?query=&flightType=departure&terminalType=domestic&date=2019-11-10&sortColumn=scheduled_time&ascending=true&showAll=true'

address = 'lhr'
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({address: address})

response_data = requests.get(url).json()
for element in response_data['flightData']:
    flight_id = element['id']
    airline = element['airline']
    destination = element['destinations']
    flightNumbers = element['flightNumbers']
    scheduledTime = element['scheduledTime']
    estimatedTime = element['estimatedTime']
    scheduledDate = element['scheduledDate']
    latestTime = element['latestTime']
    status = element['status']
    statusColor = element['statusColor']
    print(airline, destination, flightNumbers)
```

Comment: thank you so mch it worked, i i now need to add it to a mysql data base, do i just connect to the database and push     flight_id = element['id']
    airline = element['airline']
    destination = element['destinations']
    flightNumbers = element['flightNumbers']
    scheduledTime = element['scheduledTime']
    estimatedTime = element['estimatedTime']
    scheduledDate = element['scheduledDate']
    latestTime = element['latestTime']
    status = element['status']
    statusColor = element['statusColor']